# Problem to include vars in playbook Pipeline jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I'm trying to migrate all my playbooks to Jenkins, and for the moment I'm looking to do something simple, but I'm having a problem including my variables in the playbook.

**My playbook :**

```
cat ${WORKSPACE]/playbooks/test.yml :

---

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: "Include files"
    include_vars:
      file: "{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}/inventory/deploiements/vars"

...
```

**My vars file :**

```
cat ${WORKSPACE]/inventory/deploiements/vars :

---

vars1: "test1"
vars2: "test2"

...
```

****My Jenkins pipeline :****

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                ansiblePlaybook playbook: 'playbooks/test.yml', extras: '-vvv'
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I launch my playbook manually, in the workspace of my jenkins job, it works as expected:

```
[ansible@ansiblemaster test]$ pwd; ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml  -v
/data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Include files] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
mercredi 18 août 2021  09:08:35 +0200 (0:00:00.027)       0:00:00.027 *********
ok: [localhost] => {"ansible_facts": {"vars1": "test1", "vars2": "test2"}, "ansible_included_var_files": ["/data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test/inventory/deploiements/vars"], "changed": false}

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
mercredi 18 août 2021  09:08:35 +0200 (0:00:00.049)       0:00:00.076 *********
===============================================================================
Include files -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 0.05s
```

Now if I run my playbook directly from Jenkins I see this in my build result:

```
Running on ansiblemaster in /data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test
[Pipeline] ansiblePlaybook
```

=> So OK Jenkins is on his workspace correctly, then :

```
[test] $ ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml -vvv
```

..
..

```
TASK [Include files] ***********************************************************
task path: /data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test/playbooks/test.yml:6
mercredi 18 août 2021  09:10:03 +0200 (0:00:00.028)       0:00:00.028 ********* 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "ansible_included_var_files": [],
    "changed": false,
    "message": "Could not find or access '/data/jenkins_agent/inventory/deploiements/vars' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option"
}
```

I can't figure out why Jenkins is trying to include `/data/jenkins_agent/inventory/deploiements/vars` when it depends on `{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}` which i'me sure Jenkins is into `/data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test`

Can somebody help me ?

Thanks you guys.

DB

Comment: Hi. 1) variables set inside your inventory should be loaded automatically without having to include (e.g. put them in `group_vars/all.yml`). See [organizing your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) 2) if you ignore point 1, loading files based on current dir environment variable on controller is a bad idea as you have just experienced. You are "sure" (without checking?) that Jenkins is "into" a specific dir... the result is an other story (`JENKINS_HOME`). Using a relative path or `playbook_dir` would be more reliable, but I still suggest (1)

Comment: Hi @Zeitounator.
Is a simplified exemple, in my real ansible, my vars are into /inventory/deploiements/../../../. Here it is just an exemple to explain easier my problem. So yes I have to ignore the point 1. I'm not "sure" but my command `sh 'pwd'` send `/data/jenkins_agent/workspace/test` as a result..

Comment: `yes I have to ignore the point 1` <= no you don't **have** to, but you can **decide** to. In that case, those files should probably not be in your inventory dir but in a `vars` subdir somewhere so you could take advantage of [local path magic](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbook_pathing.html#the-magic-of-local-paths). And regarding your test, you are not verifying the same thing: result of the pwd command inside sh in you pipeline as compared to the `PWD` env var content when ansible-playbook starts =>  `- debug: msg="{{ lookup('env','PWD') }}"`

Comment: I tested, the debug results is `"msg": "/data/jenkins_agent"` .. So why Jenkins is at this moment in the `$JENKINS_HOME` while he's in `$WORKSPACE` in my `sh 'pwd'` test..

Comment: Because jenkins is running as a process which started in `JENKINS_HOME` when it was first initialized (by systemctl or whatever start command you used). As I told you in my first comment, it's a really bad idea, don't do it.